# defining multiple timers using the alarm function in c

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals, alarm

I created a program that uses two functions: mytimer and my_clear_all. The process defines a certain number of timers, using the `alarm` function. The alarm function is a timer, which expires after the time given as a parameter.

The code seems a little superficial to me, but I have a starting point in what I want next. I want you to help me better understand the use of timers (I do not mean software timers in Linux). How can I modify the program to implement a set of functions that allow a process to define a number of timers (using `alarm`)?
I would also like to avoid using the `printf` function for asynchronous signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<signal.h>

//global variables
int t1 = 0;
int t2 = 1000; 
int start = 0;

void mytimer(int t) {
if (start == 0) {
start =1;
alarm(1);
}
int tf = t1+t;
if (tf < t2) {
t2 = tf;
}
printf("Inside mytimer function texit= %d\n",tf);
}

void my_clear_all(void) {
t2 = 1000;
}

void sig_handler(int signum){
 
  if(signum == SIGALRM){         //signal handler for SIGALRM
    t1++;
    //printf("Inside handler function t= %d\n",t1);
    if (t1<t2){
    alarm(1);
    }
    else{
    //printf("Inside exit function texit= %d\n",t2);
    exit(0);   
    }
  }
}
 
int main(){ 
 int i;
  signal(SIGALRM,sig_handler); // Register signal handler

 mytimer(7); 
 mytimer(5);
 my_clear_all();  // timer deletion function test
  i=0;
  while(i < 10){ 
    printf("t= %d : Inside main i= %d \n",t1,i);
    sleep(1);
    i++;
  }
  
 mytimer(5);  // mytimer function test
 mytimer(7);
  i=0;
  while(i < 10){ 
    printf("t= %d : Inside main i= %d \n",t1,i);
    sleep(1);
    i++;
  } 
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want [`timer_create()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) instead.

Comment: Or maybe [`timerfd_create()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and avoid signals.

Answer (score 2):

From the alarm manpage:

```
 DESCRIPTION
   alarm()  arranges  for  a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling
   process in seconds seconds.

   If seconds is zero, any pending alarm is canceled.

   In any event any previously set alarm() is canceled.
```

You can not set multiple alarms. Instead you have to write your own data structure to manage timers and set the system alarm to fire for when the next timer will expire.

A good structure for this is a min heap, with the timer that expires next always at the top.